# Le sens de l'expression « est beau comme l’antique »

Tags: expressions

Je lisais [cet article](http://www.alterecoplus.fr/quand-messieurs-cahuc-et-zylberberg-decouvrent-la-science/00012139), et j'y trouve l'expression suivante : « est beau comme l'antique ». Pourriez-vous m'aider à lui trouver un sens ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

« Beau comme l'antique »  est une expression qui veut dire que c'est beau comme une œuvre de l'antiquité, les œuvres d'art de l'antiquité étant censées être « belles » et représenter le summum de la beauté. En général ça se dit pour une œuvre d'art, ou du moins dans un contexte artistique.
Par exemple ce mot attribué au [peintre David](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques-Louis_David) à l'issue de sa première rencontre avec [Bonaparte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon) :

> « Oh ! Mes amis quelle belle tête il a ! C'est pur, c'est grand, c'est beau comme l'antique ! (…) Enfin, mes amis, c'est un homme auquel on aurait élevé des autels dans l'antiquité ; oui, mes amis ; oui, mes chers amis ! Bonaparte est mon héros !. »

Voir l'expression dans le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/antique).

L'auteur de l'article de presse que tu cites applique le qualificatif à la façon dont les auteurs du livre dont il fait la critique traitent leur sujet. Dans sa critique il reproche à ces auteurs d'enrober leur manque de connaissance du sujet dans un mise en scène intellectuelle.

L'emploi de l'expression est ici un peu surprenant mais ça permet à celui qui a rédigé de faire ressortir que la seule qualité des auteurs en question c'est d'avoir dupé lecteurs et critiques qui ont fait la louange de ce livre.

Comment: Merci, Laure. ;)

Comment: En lisant l'article, je ne trouve pas le sujet de "est beau comme l'antique"... Si c'est "la mise en scène", c'est féminin, donc on devrait accorder non ? Et tout le reste est au pluriel...

Comment: @Random Le sujet ne peut-être (à mon humble avis) que « ceci », que je comprends (à mon encore plus humble avis) comme la façon de procéder des auteurs du livre : [mise en scène ... aux faits]. J'ai dû m'y reprendre à plusieurs fois pour comprendre ce passage, d'ailleurs je viens de voir que l'auteur de l'article est non pas journaliste comme je l'avais d'abord dit mais économiste et universitaire lui-même comme les deux auteurs du livre dont il a fait la critique...

Comment: @Laure Oui peut-être... La phrase est vraiment compliquée à lire, avec toutes les virgules d'aparté...